# Passing numeric element to object

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

I am working on a NodeJS addon project and i couldn't really understand how to pass a long value into my object.

Here is my code:

```
#include <node.h>
namespace NODEAPP
{
using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
using v8::Isolate;
using v8::Local;
using v8::Object;
using v8::String;
using v8::Value;
using v8::Handle;
void fooFunc(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args)
{
    long foo = 51294;
    long bar = 91923;
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
    Local<Object> obj = Object::New(isolate);
    obj->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "msg"), wanna pass foo here);
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(obj);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: We need to know your definitions of `FunctionCallbackInfo` and `Value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out.

Here it is:

```
obj->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "msg"), v8::Integer::New(isolate, foo));
```

Comment: All the javascript types have similar constructors.  Integer, Number (floats), String, Date, etc